# trim method giving error in IE 8

Tags: jquery

I am removing extra space using trim method which is working fine in all browser except IE8.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('a').click(function(){
console.log($('div').text().trim())
})})
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>   test </div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">pick test</a>
</body>
```

Comment: IE8 doesn't have a `String.prototype.trim()` method.

Comment: it could be the issue with `console.log` and not the `trim` . Change that to `alert` and see if it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jQuery's trim:

```
$.trim($('div').text())
```

`text()` returns a string so you are trying to use the browser's built in `trim` which IE8 does not have.

Answer (score 1):

try below

```
$.trim($('div').text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.trim()` jquery method instead:

```
console.log($.trim($('div').text()))
```